# Slider is hanging if lot of items to slide

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I have horizontal list about 10000 items and to scroll I am using a flutter slider but it is not smooth at all. I think setting the state on change valve is not a proper way.

````
                                            Slider(
                                              key: ValueKey('slider'),
                                              activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                              inactiveColor: Colors.white,
                                              min: 0.0,
                                              max: scrollController.hasClients
                                                  ? scrollController
                                                      .position.maxScrollExtent
                                                  : 10000.0,
                                              value: value,
                                              onChanged: (double value) {
                                                scrollController.position
                                                    .jumpTo(value);
                                                if (mounted)
                                                  setState(
                                                      () => this.value = value);
                                              },
                                              onChangeStart: (double value) {},
                                              onChangeEnd: (double value) {
                                              },
                                            )```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips to make it faster:

- Instead of using `min: 0.0` and `max: 10000.0` you could leave the
  default values to work from `0.0` to `1.0` and then multiply the
  `value * 10000.0`, this way the `Slider` doesn't have to calculate
  the position for values from `0.0` to `10000.0` but from `0.0` to
  `1.0`.
- It would be good if the `setState()` just updates the `Slider`
  and not the whole tree of widgets. To do that you could put the
  `Slider` in a `StatefulWidget`, or you could wrap the `Slider` with a
  `StatefulBuilder`.
- Running the app in `release` mode will be faster than in
  `debug` mode.

Here is a quick example, using `StatefulBuilder`:

```
StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (context, setState) {
    return Slider(
      value: value,
      onChanged: (value) {
        _scrollController.position.jumpTo(value * 10000);
        setState(() {
          this.value = value;
        });
      },
    );
  },
)
```

Comment: But i am getting error ==>I/flutter (18521): 'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 132 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.

Comment: Make sure you are setting this.value = value; and not the value * 10000